# Sybase equivalent of MSSQL OUTPUT INTO

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sap-ase

I've tried googling around with no luck.

I am aware of Sybase's output ability into a file, but I am trying to find out if it can also output into another table after an update, much like MSSQL's:

```
UPDATE Table1
OUTPUT inserted.ID
INTO @TempOfIDs
WHERE ID IN (x,y,z)
```

If not, is there any Sybase trick to mimic this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways of doing this: either you run a SELECT query with the same WHERE-clause and pick up the current values of those columns (since you're looking for the new values after the update), or you use a trigger to capture these values -- though in that case you won't be able to put these values into a table variable.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a whole new select due to the table sizes I'm dealing with. But as I have been finding out these past weeks, sybase is just not as nice as mssql server.